# Removing lines from contourf graphs

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

Hi all
I'm using scripts for generating plots easily and with exactly the same layout.

That's why I'd like to create `contourf` graph of given data automaticcaly without black contour lines. I can do it manually by advanced figure layout, byt is there a command for it?

Thanks for suggestions; I have no idea how to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the black lines by setting the `'LineColor'` property to `'none'`, either in the initial call to [CONTOURF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contourf.html):

```
contourf(peaks(20),10,'LineColor','none');
```

Or by modifying the handle graphics object after creating it:

```
[C,h] = contourf(peaks(20),10);
set(h,'LineColor','none');
```

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you can do with manual editing you can also do programmatically. For `contourf`, you can do the following:

```
[~,h] = contourf(peaks(20),10);
set(h,'LineColor','none')
```

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contourgroupproperties.html) for all the properties you can modify using the `set` command.

Comment: That's why I'm asking. The figure window is just GUI operating with those commands. But it doesn't show them.

Answer (score 2):

```
'shading flat' will do the job.
```